Update *ansi-term* buffer name
When running a Bash in a Xterm it is possible to update the window title by some escape sequence. Is something similar possible with ansi-term? If I open more than one ansi-term the buffers are enumerated:
*ansi-term*
*ansi-term*<2>
*ansi-term*<3>

This is not very useful. I would like to have the working directory of the shell in the buffer name.

Have you read manual about Uniquify? I suspect you can customize the buffer naming behavior this way.
